# Linked lists deleting

Tags: c++, pointers

When moving through a linked list, and creating a temp pointer to move through it, do we have to delete the tmp pointer or does it delete automatically. I understand for allocating new memory, with the new operator we need to delete the memory allocated for the pointer, and than set the pointer to null, but if we just have a pointer, i.e

```
Node*follow=head; //where head is a pointer to a linked list
```

at the end do we need to delete follow? even if it's not allocating new memory I'm just using it to move through the list?

```
int countNum (Node *head, int key)
{
    int count=0;

    if (head == nullptr)
        return 0;

    Node *follow=head;

    while (follow != nullptr) 
    {
        if(follow->val == key)
            count++;

        follow=follow->next;
    }

    cout << count;
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    Node *head = (1,cons(2,cons(2,(cons(4,(cons(5,nullptr)))))));

    int counts=0;

    counts= countNum(head,2);

    cout<< counts<< head;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to complie this but it crashes and says the int counts=0; is a thread breakpoint? and that my Node*head=(1,cons(2,cons(2,(cons(4,(cons(5,nullptr))))))); is being unused..

Comment: Please do summat with the indentation

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to delete "the pointer" (and in fact shouldn't), because deletion is for *allocated memory*. Pointers are just a way to refer to parts of allocated memory.

This code...

```
delete ptr;
```

...doesn't delete the pointer named `ptr` - rather, it deletes the allocated memory *pointed to* by `ptr`. In fact, its effect is identical to this code:

```
ptr2 = ptr;
delete ptr2;
```

Because again, it's deleteing the same allocated memory, since `ptr` and `ptr2` are made to point to the same place. The names/locations of the pointers themselves are irrelevant; it's where they're pointing that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a pointer is like declaring any (int,double etc.) variable. when you delete on a pointer, you delete the memory which the pointer is pointing to and not the pointer itself.